# How to implement a 3d card animation in react native

Tags: react-native, animation, expo

Can someone provide me any library or refrences to implement this animation in react native

https://youtube.com/shorts/VEPfxfUwQAQ?feature=shared
Very similar to something like this done in react: https://3d-flip-cards.netlify.app/

I can use pangesture handler to implement the touch animation but how to implement the 3d image and 3d card